# multiple string replace in one reg expression codition

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Here is my string

```
string str = "++10+++10++++10";
```

and I have tried this regex

```
str.replace(/(\+\+||\+\+\+||\+\+\+\+)/g, '+');
```

how to replace these plus are in one plus like
`'+10+10+10'`.help me.

Comment: are you trying to replace multiple '+' with single '+'? and tag the programming language you are using for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
"++10+++10++++10".replace(/\++/g, "+")
```